# Two index column in Indexed Db not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I am using Indexed Db for my application

I have a table product where I have added two indexes

```
 var product = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore("product", { keyPath: product_id" });
 product.createIndex("productIndex", "product_id", { unique: true });
 product.createIndex("barCodeIndex", "ean_product", { unique: false });
```

In my code, first I am searching on product id , if the result is null , I am 
searching on bar code . The problem is the code that I have written is working 
fine in Chrome and IE 10 but is not working in FF. Please suggest.

In the else part where I am searching on barcode , the line 
" var keyBarcode = barcodeSearch.index("barCodeIndex");" throws exception 
*"The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being opened."*

```
   var searchKey = IDBKeyRange.only(productId);
    var productSearch = localDatabase.db.transaction("product").objectStore("product");
    var key = productSearch.index("productIndex");
  key.get(searchKey).onsuccess = function (evt) {
        var productSearchResult = evt.target.result;
        if (productSearchResult != null) {
         //some logic

        } else {
            //search on bar code
            var barcode = $("#txtProductCode").val().trim();
            var barcodeKey = IDBKeyRange.only(barcode);
            var barcodeSearch = localDatabase.db.transaction("product").objectStore("product");

                var keyBarcode = barcodeSearch.index("barCodeIndex");
                keyBarcode.get(barcodeKey).onsuccess = function(event) {
                    var barcodeSearchResult = event.target.result;

                    if (barcodeSearchResult != null) {
                        //some logic                     
                    } 

                };

        }

    };
```

Comment: Could you post runnable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue on my own .

There was issue with casing. The index created on table was "BarCodeIndex"  and I was trying to use "barCodeIndex".

```
Point to be noted : Index names are case sensitive
```